# Stop SimpleHttpSever in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, simplehttpserver

I am using SimpleHTTPServer in jupyter notebook like this:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

It works good, but how can I stop it later in next input block?

Comment: linux or osx ??

Comment: Does `httpd.shutdown()` fail to work for you?

Comment: @9000 Exactly! This command really does fail for my. The command executes without error, but server is still up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you can't.

You're unable to reference previous cells (or the results of) inside of Jupyter Notebook - [see this open issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1098) for more details on the discussion.

This means you can't manipulate the object once you've used the serve_forever() function.

It may however be possible to rewrite serve_forever to fit your needs. Currently it will literally serve no matter what but adding a condition that allows you to connect and issue a 'shutdown' command would circumvent the need to call up the object later. You could just connect to the socket and issue a customised header that the TCP server would pick up and respond to.

As a quick example to start you on this path:

```
class StoppableRPCServer(SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer):

    def serve_forever(self):
            while not self.stopped:
                self.handle_request()

    def not_forever(self):
        # Called from another function when a custom header is detected
        self.stopped = True
        self.server_close()
```

Answer (score 0):

the server are running in background you need to search the PID an kill it like:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

Netstat out:

```
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:8888  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      12332/python
```

Kill PID with pkill or kill:

```
kill 12332
```

Comment: These commands are for terminal, are not they? How is this applicable in jupyter notebook?

Comment: @matousc: You could run these commands using `Popen`, parse output, etc, provided that you're running on a Posix system. The problem is that probably the `kill` will kill the whole Jupyter process, not just the HTTP server.